# Difference or similarity in latent variables or SEM models

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, differences

There are five **latent variables** (three independent and two dependent) which constitute a PLS-SEM model.
A single survey was conducted; however, the questions were **asked twice** to the **same participants**. The items were worded identically, only the subject of the sentence was replaced, to represent two different aspects.
In summary, there is a single model with two datasets, which can be paired as the two variants were measured at the same time.
I would like to ask two questions:

1. Is there any way to statistically prove the difference or similarity between the correspondent **latent variables** (pairwise) separately?
2. Is it possible to perform a similar procedure for **the SEM models** to assess the difference or similarity in the results?

Thank you very much for your help and advice in advance!

Comment: You can look for articles about longitudinal CFA / measurement invariance. The same methods apply to any kind of repeated measures, not just occasions.

Comment: Thank you very much! According to your suggestion, I used invariance measurement based on the following [description](https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/intro-basics-longitudinal-measurement-invariance).